# This method must return a result of type double

Tags: java

```
public double getBalance(int account){
    for(int i=0; i<this.account.size(); i++) {
        BankAccount anAccount = this.account.get(i);
        if(anAccount.getAccountNumber()==account) {
            double balance = anAccount.getBalance();
            return balance;
        }
    }
}
```

The error this method gives me is that the method must return a result of type double even tho I clearly return balance which is from the getBalance() method which returns a double. Why doesn't it work? I don't understand.

Comment: When there is no matching account you could `return 0;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `return` statement in an `if` block, so you are not always returning `double`. so compiler gives you error.

You need another `return` out of there.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't because since there is a *missing `return`* statement.

Think of what would you do if `anAccount.getAccountNumber() != account`?

When you handle such cases and return an appropriate/default value for such cases, the compile error should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible (if the account is never found) for your method not to return anything.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a return statement, not every path returns a value:

```
/**
 * Takes the id of an account, returns the balance.
 * @param account The account id
 * @return The balance of the account or -1.0 if the account is not found.
 */
public double getBalance(int account) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.account.size(); i++) {
        BankAccount anAccount = this.account.get(i);
        if (anAccount.getAccountNumber() == account) {
            double balance = anAccount.getBalance();
            return balance;
        }
    }

    return -1.0;
}
```

---

You'd want to check if the account exists before calling this function though, since -1.0 could probably be a valid balance, I just used it to show what you're missing.

Comment: returning `null` would be better than `-1.0`

Comment: @suvojit_007 How do you suggest I return `null` in a method with return type `double`?

Comment: @suvojit_007 You litterally cannot return `null` in a method with return type `double` though, which is what I'm trying to say. If it were `Double` or `Optional<Double>` you could do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Because if the "if" condition will be false for all for loop iterations, the method will have nothing to return...

Answer (score 0):

What will happens if `this.account.size()` will be zero or less? Your method must return a value but you didn't defined it.

Same for inner if condition, must return value if not true